# Model.delete() not called for child entities when parent is deleted in Play Framework

Tags: java, jpa, playframework-2.0, ebean

In the code below, I override `save()` and `delete()` for the `CityImage` class in order to upload/remove images from Amazon S3 when they are added/removed from the database.

```
@Entity
public class City extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<CityImage> images;
}

@Entity
public class CityImage extends Model {

    @Id
    public Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    public City city;

    @Override
    public void delete() {
        deleteFromAmazonS3();
        super.delete();
    }

    @Override
    public void save() {
        super.save();
        saveOnAmazonS3();
    }
}
```

The problem: when I call `delete()` on a `City` object, I would expect Play/Ebean to call `delete()` on all `CityImage` objects that reference it, but this doesn't happen. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `orphanRemoval` to your association.

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
public List<CityImage> images;
```